# Allocating memory using malloc and find the strlen()

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, strlen

```
int main(){
    char *ptr = (char*)malloc(10);
    printf("%d",strlen(ptr));
}
```

Output is 11. i did not get why it is like that?

Answer (score 7):

You haven't written any data to your malloc'ed block.  It has old bytes in it, there's no way to know what it contains.  `strlen` simply looks for the next zero byte.  I guess you found one 11 bytes away, but it could have been thousands of bytes away.

You are looking at Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating 10 bytes of memory that might be storing garbage. Remember, strlen() reads until a `\0` is found.

Ideally, after allocating a new block you would execute: `memset(ptr, 0, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is returning 11, but that is **just a coincidence**. In general you get undefined behaviour.

The problem is that in C string is **null terminated**. That means the \0 character denotes end of string.

```
int main(){
    char *ptr = (char*)malloc(11);
    ptr[10]=0;
    printf("%d",strlen(ptr));
}
```

This will return a value <= 10. Always.

Comment: Not always. Any of the intervening bytes could be '\0' as well.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
int main(){ 
    char *ptr = (char*)malloc(10); 
    memcpy(ptr,0,10); 
    printf("%d",strlen(ptr)); 
}
```